# paginate in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

can anyone suggest me how to remove undefined method 'paginate' in rails 2.3.8
here is my index method which shows index page and code of this is

```
 def index
    @clients = Client.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
    respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @clients }
        end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined method 'paginate' probably indicates that you don't have **will_paginate** installed.

To get rid of your error you have to choices:

1) Get rid of pagination.
Replace

```
@clients = Client.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
```

With

```
@clients = Client.all
```

2) Install will_paginate by placing the following in your environment file:

```
config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '~> 2.3.16'
```

and then running **rake gems:install** of cause. :)

Comment: thnx Godsaur, it was useful for me

Comment: thnx Godsaur, it was useful for me